# applicationContext.xml not reading servletContext.contextPath

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Im trying to read a properties file from an external location and I am trynig to use the contextPath name as the file's names beacuse I will run multiple instances of the app on he same server. I'm currently using SpringFramework 3.1.4

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/configFolder/#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties" />
```

the file name ends up being `/configFolder/#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties`
It does not replace the variable
is there another way to get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:/config/#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Something very close to this worked for me in Spring 4.0.4 in my application-context.xml file.

#{servletContext.contextPath} works but it starts with a forward slash, e.g. "/app-name" so the line above needed to be:

`<property name="location" value="file:/config#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties" />`

That looks ugly without the natural / between file:/config and #{servletContext.contextPath} but it did work.

Answer (score 2):

`#{servletContext.contextPath}` is a variable only known in JSP and Facelets through Expression Language. This won't work in Spring. You should put your configuration file inside a resource folder in your jar and retrieve it from there instead.

You state that this worked in other projects but that was because Spring supported a variable called `servletContext` (which IMO is wrong). Looks like Spring MVC 3.2 doesn't support this anymore, as explained here: [Resolving servletContext.contextPath Expression in Spring 3.2](http://www.xephyrus.com/pod/2013/08/resolving_servletcontextcontextpath_expression_in_spring_32/).

Comment: your answer is my current scenario, I need to this because I Did this on another project that had its configurations on a spring.xml file and it worked just fine

Comment: Luiggi Ill try this solution tommorow in the mourning if it works I'll accept the answer